# Optimization Calculus Problem- Flight

Tags: calculus, optimization

If exactly 230 people sign up for a charter flight, the operators of a charter airline charge Dollars 330 for a round-trip ticket. However, if more than 230 people sign up for the flight, then fare is reduced by Dollar 1 for each additional person. Assuming that more than 230 people sign up, determine how many passengers will result in a maximum revenue for the travel agency.

I have this for homework and all I could come up with was that maybe i should be using some sort of revenue equation but I am not sure how to set it up.

R=Price* Number of things sold
I know that I need another equation to get here. What I had before was R=230? and then 330?
After this I know I need to derive to find the equation and then set it equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

in general the revenue is $R=p\cdot x$. With 230 People: $R=230 \cdot 330$. Now you can raise the number of people by y (persons) and reduce the price by y (Dollars): $R=(230+y)\cdot (330-y)$
You can maximize the revenue by derivating $R(y)$ in respect to y and set it 0.

greetings,

calculus